# Where should I start to learn cryptography?

Tags: encryption, hash, authentication

I want to learn cryptography. I just wanted to ask people who are experienced about the field where I should start. Any recommendation would be something for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related questions : https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6810/where-can-i-begin-to-study-the-math-behind-modern-cryptography https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10467/what-is-the-lowest-level-of-mathematics-required-in-order-to-understand-how-encr?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/getting-started?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61717/which-branches-of-mathematics-are-most-important-to-understand-cryptography https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31/current-mathematics-theory-used-in-cryptography-coding-theory

Comment: The questioner asked about learning cryptography, and was then shifted into answers about learning math. Hundreds of university courses teach basic cryptography, and they do not start with math.  In fact, there is very little math involved.  I worry that marking this question as a duplicate will discourage the questioner.

Comment: "I want to be a cryptographer"--OK, let's start talking math.  "I want to learn cryptography so I can protect data"--OK, let's talk about ciphers, hashes, HMAC, etc. "I want to learn cryptography"--could you tell us the level you want to reach?

Comment: @BardanAdam   I hope you received an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: Have to agree with @Patriot re. discouragement.  Other than appreciating that $2^{128}$ = boiling of all Earth's lakes, I see no need for maths.  Maybe a wee bit of $log(choices)$ to determine entropy content, but only if we truly understand $choices$.  The Zeitgeist says that we mustn't _"roll our own"_, therefore all that remains is selection and implementation of _"approved"_ crypto schemes.  Is anyone here sufficiently competent to produce a curve that Wall Street will standardise on?  What use finite fields with BouncyCastle? Ergo, no maths.

Comment: @PaulUszak Are you actually saying, on a cryptography site, that there is no need for maths?

Comment: @forest  I am sure Paul did not mean that. He'll clarify.

Answer (score 0):

https://gnupg.org/documentation/index.html

Not experienced, just sharing one of the ways, which working for me (Online identity verification issues -> Web of trust -> PGP -> Cryptography).

Comment: Well reading FAQ and documentation seems like a good idea. You might enjoy this https://philzimmermann.com/EN/essays/index.html